# Can we concatenate several RUN instructions with --no-cache in Dockerfile

Tags: go, dockerfile

I was writing a Dockerfile and i have concatenated several RUN instructions into one for proper caching but i realised one of the RUN instruction having --no-cache. Could you please advise how the caching will work here.

```
RUN go mod download \
&& apk update --no-cache \
&& apk add git \
&& CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o golang-sdk .
```

Comment: The --no-cache flag is an apk option. It has no impact at all on if and how docker uses cached layers, and it's unclear to me why you think it might.

Comment: The purpose of concatenating several RUN instructions is for caching. In the above example one of the instruction which as been concatenated is not using caching this means cached layer will not be used. Please correct my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The `apk update --no-cache` does not make sense. Strike it and modify the git install to

```
RUN apk add git --no-cache \
&& go mod download \
&& CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o golang-sdk .
```

Even better: do a two stage build:

```
FROM golang:latest AS build
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/you/project/
RUN [yourstuff]
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=build /go/src/github.com/you/project/app .
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/app"]
```

This way, you can do all the stuff you like while building without needing to think about image sizes, and have the smallest possible image for `app`.

Comment: My questions is around how caching works where one of the instruction is having --no-cache and another one is trying to download dependencies.

Comment: @SudhirKumar --no-cache is a well documented instruction of `apk`. `apk update` is there to download the latest package information, and `--no-cache` tells it to discard them.